# Rails assigning names to variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a user ranking system, and am trying to assign `user.rank` values with a name.
I wanted to define something like this in my User model and then be able to reference it when displaying each user's rank, but this probably isn't the best way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  RANK_NAMES = {
   'Peasant'   => (0..75),
   'Craftsman' => (76..250),
   'Vassal'    => (251..750),
   'Noble'     => (750..1500),
   'Monarch'   => (1501..999999)
  }
```

Perhaps it would be better to define a method in a controller or helper like:

```
if user.rank == 0..75
  rank_name = "Peasant"
elsif...
```

But not sure how to do that. Anyone have any thoughts? I'm not even sure what to call what it is I'm trying to do, thus making it difficult to research on my own.

Comment: Are your `=` and `==` backwards?

Comment: I would consider breaking this out into a separate model because you may wish to add/edit/remove ranks. Although it may seem relevant to place this in `User` you are introducing a tight coupling between `User` and what is essentially a `RankClassification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something even as simple as this, assuming user.rank exists.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def rank_name
    case self.rank
      when 0..75
        'Peasant'
      when 76..250
        'Craftsman'
      when 251..750
        'Vassal'
      when 750..1500
        'Noble'
      when 1501..999999
        'Monarch'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I just wasn't sure how to properly write it. Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 0):

If `rank_name` is *specific* to the `User`, I'd make it a method of `User`.

You could try something like below. It might give you some ideas.

```
class User
  RANKS = [
    {:name => 'Peasant', :min => 0, :max => 75},
    {:name => 'Craftsman', :min => 76, :max => 250}
    # ...
  ]

  attr_accessor :rank

  def rank_name
    # TODO what happens if rank is out of range of all ranks or rank is nil
    # or not an integer
    User::RANKS[rank_index][:name]
  end

  private

  def rank_index
    User::RANKS.index { |r| (r[:min]..r[:max]).include? @rank }
  end
end

user = User.new
user.rank = 76
puts user.rank_name # -> Craftsman
```